# Write out a letter every interval every ms multithreading java

Tags: java, multithreading, printing, synchronization

I'm currently working on a problem where I have to:

Write out a letter, x amount of times, after x amount of ms. Use 4 multithreads, 3 of them start right away 1 of them starts when one of the 3 is finished.

For example: A, 10, 100, has to write out A ever 10 times every 100 miliseconds.

Im currently stuck on syncing the multithreads for them to work together at adding one sum rather than them working seporatley. Could you advise how to sync it together for it to write out the above?

Here is my code:

```java
public class PrinterThread extends Thread {

    private String letter;
    private int internal;
    private int amount;

    
    public PrinterThread() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= internal; i++) {
            System.out.println(letter);
        }
        synchronized (this){
            internal++;
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(amount);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {



        PrinterThread printerThread = new PrinterThread();
        PrinterThread printerThread1 = new PrinterThread();
        PrinterThread printerThread2 = new PrinterThread();
        PrinterThread printerThread3 = new PrinterThread();

        printerThread.run();
        printerThread1.run();
        printerThread2.run();
        printerThread3.run();

    }
}
```

Comment: Start by: 1. Create a constructor for all the parameters, 2. `implements Runnable` instead of `extends Thread`, 3. Don't increment `internal` 4. Rename `internal` to something meaningful - perhaps `quantity`

Comment: @Bohemian Ive got this done, could you advise on how to sync it?

Comment: Sync what? There's nothing I can see that needs synchronising.

Comment: I suggest you edit to drop the aspect of repeating the output of text as that seems irrelevant to your main question.

Comment: You said: "… when one of the 3 is finished ". When does a `PrinterThread` finish? As you have described it, each one runs infinitely, writing text every so often, endlessly. If the last task should start only after one of the earlier have finished, what defines an earlier task finishing?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `BlockingQueue` for synchronisation, but you do need to `join` with the threads from your main method otherwise your main will exit the JVM before the threads finish (or possibly even before they start).

```
public class PrinterThread implements Runnable {
    private String letter;
    private int copies;
    private int amount;
    
    public PrinterThread(String letter, int copies, int amount) {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.copies = copies;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < copies; i++) { 
            System.out.println(letter.repeat(copies));

            try {
                Thread.sleep(amount);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        QUEUE.offer(0);
    }
}

public class Main {

    private static BlockingQueue<Integer> QUEUE = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(4); // at least as large as the number of threads

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread printerThread1 = new Thread(new PrinterThread("A", 10, 100));
        Thread printerThread2 = new Thread(new PrinterThread("B", 20, 50));
        // etc

        printerThread1.start();
        printerThread2.start();
        // etc

        QUEUE.take(); // blocking call
        new Thread(new PrinterThread("D", 30, 80)).start();

        // wait for threads to finish
        printerThread1.join();
        printerThread2.join();
        // etc
    }
}
```

<sub>Disclaimer: This answer was thumbed in via my phone, so it may not work correctly or even compile, but there’s a good chance it will work.</sub>

Comment: The Question asks for the last task to begin only after one of the earlier tasks completes. I don't see that happening here in this Answer.

Comment: See my last comment on the Question. I don't read any requirement justifying your `for` loop on `copies`. In my reading of the Question, the task is infinite. Perhaps I've misread, in which case you are correct.

Comment: Another issue, the Question seems to ask for the last task to start only after *any* of the earlier tasks completes. Your code does not start the last task until *all* of the earlier tasks are done. Or have I misunderstood `Thread#join`? I thought the `join` method blocks.

Comment: @basil yes, join blocks. I find the question confusing. I'll have to rework this (if I have time).

Comment: Yes, confusing Question. I voted to close after attempting my own Answer using executor service. You deserve more than my up-vote for making the attempt to answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque I *think* I've done it :)

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for your input. Although Bohemian was correct. I'm trying to use 3 threads to work at the same time & the 4th to start when one of the 3 finishes. By using join() its being done one by one, not 3 at once. 
- Also Im trying to write out  A, 10, 100, has to write out A ever 10 times every 100 miliseconds with the use of those 4 multithreads. 
- At the moment with the use of constructor I make 1 thread per letter. Whereas I need 4 for one letter.

Comment: @wieszak09 You have not explained how any of the first three threads ever ends.

Answer (score 0):

> Write out a letter, x amount of times, after x amount of ms. Use 4 multithreads, 3 of them start right away 1 of them starts when one of the 3 is finished.

You obviously need to create a `PrinterThread`  constructor which takes the letter, the amount of times, and amount of millis.

> I'm currently stuck on syncing the multithreads for them to work together at adding one sum rather than them working separately.

I'm not sure about the sum.  If you are asking how you can start the 3rd thread then there are a number of different ways to do this.  I would lock on a lock object and pass in a `boolean` in the constructor about whether or not the thread should `wait()` on the lock.  As each of the other threads finish they would call `notify()` on the lock.

```
 private static final Object lock = new Object();
 ...

 public class PrinterThread {
    public PrinterThread(char letter, int times, int millis, boolean waitForOthers) {
        this.letter = letter;
        this.times = times;
        this.millis = millis;
        if (waitForOthers) {
           synchronized (lock) {
              // wait for one of the others to notify us
              lock.wait();
           }
        }
    }
    public void run() {
       ...
       synchronized (lock) {
          // notify the lock in case another thread is waiting
          lock.notify();
       }
 }
```

Then start 3 `PrinterThread`s with a value of `false` and 1 of them with a value of `true` so that it waits.